# How to unrar a file?

Tags: command-line, rar

I tried to unrar the file `Starbound 1.2.2.rar` with the command

```
unrar x Starbound 1.2.2.rar
```

and many varitions, how can I `unrar` this file?

Comment: Have you tried unrar x "Starbound 1.2.2.rar"? What happens when you try?

Comment: It says : invalid archive 'x' : bad adress, then gives me the usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access files/directories with spaces in the name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516772/how-to-access-files-directories-with-spaces-in-the-name)

Answer (score 3):

Your filename has a space in it.
Try:

```
unrar x Starbound\ 1.2.2.rar
```

or

```
unrar x "Starbound 1.2.2.rar"
```

Comment: The slash is necessary because without escaping the space `unrar` tries to open the two files `Starbound` and `1.2.2.rar` – and fails. An alternative is quoting, either `"Starbound 1.2.2.rar"` or `'Starbound 1.2.2.rar'` is possible here. You're welcome to add this explanation to your answer.